# What is the reason for std::memcpy not being constexpr even in C++20?

Tags: c++, constexpr, c++20

I understand that copying arbitrary chunks of memory is not always possible to do at compile time but since we are getting constexpr containers, virtual methods and also algorithms, why not memcpy too? It is too a kind of algorithm.

Furthemore,

- C++20 `std::bit_cast` seems a lot like `std::memcpy` workaround `reinterpret_cast` but it is `constexpr`.
- `std::copy` using iterators is marked as `constexpr` for C++20, so copying is somehow possible for types.

The usage would be to either copy or just "reinterpret" variables/arrays in `constexpr` functions, the former is not solved by `std::bit_cast` AFAIK. In particular, the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64040944/can-i-reinterpret-cast-the-parameter-of-a-constexpr-function) and my answer would like to use it.

- Is there any particular reason for why `std::bit_cast` can be constexpr but `std::memcpy` cannot?
- Does it have to do with memcpy using void pointers instead of typed references?
- Not actually having to copy anything?
- C backwards compatibility?
- Maybe because there is no support for a "pointer to constexpr memory"? But the same applies to the reference parameter in `std::bit_cast` and iterators in `std::copy`.

Relevant answer to [C++20 bit_cast vs reinterpret_cast](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53402217/7691729) briefly cites from somewhere:

> Furthermore, it is currently impossible to implement a constexpr
> bit-cast function, as memcpy itself isn’t constexpr. Marking the
> proposed function as constexpr doesn’t require or prevent memcpy from
> becoming constexpr, but requires compiler support. This leaves
> implementations free to use their own internal solution (e.g. LLVM has
> a bitcast opcode).

But it does not go into detail of not making it constexpr too.

Note, that I do not ask for why `std::bit_cast` exists. I like it, it provides a clear intention instead of `std::memcpy` workaround.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The C++ object model in runtime code is generally treated somewhat loosely. It has fairly strict rules, but there are a bunch of backdoors that are either allowed or declared UB. The latter means that you can still write code to do it, but C++ guarantees nothing about the behavior of that code.

Within constant evaluation (aka: compile-time execution of code), this is *not* the case. The restrictions on `constexpr` are specifically intended to allow the object model to be a real thing that you must follow, with no viable backdoors. And even the ones that it occasionally permits are explicitly required to be ill-formed and produce a compile-error, rather than being silent UB.

Basically at runtime, you get to treat memory as just bytes of storage. At compile-time, you *can't*; you're not allowed to. Even with dynamic allocation in `constexpr` code added in C++20, you don't get to play a lot of the games you usually get to play with that sort of thing.

`memcpy` deals in bytes of storage, copying them back and forth with no idea what they mean. `bit_cast` *knows* both the source and destination objects, and it will not allow you to do it unless the source and destination objects are appropriate for `bit_cast`ing (ie: trivially-copyable).

`bit_cast` also has [very specific restrictions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast) on the *content* of both such objects if you want it to work at compile-time. In particular, you can't `bit_cast` pointers or any objects *containing* pointers of any kind. Or references.

This is because pointers at compile-time are not just addresses. In order to catch UB, a compile-time pointer has to know the true dynamic type of the object it points to. So pointer conversions that just convert the address aren't allowed at compile-time.

Comment: Thank you for an answer, sorry for the inactivity. Can you please address `std::copy` being constexpr? Do the same restriction as to `bitcast` apply? How can it work then, since every iterator should contain at least a reference to the container.

Comment: @Quimby: What is there to address? Do not confuse implementation with behavior. `std::copy` copies objects; that is its behavior. `std::copy` is `constexpr`; that is also its behavior. What happens *within* that function to *create* that behavior is none of your business and ultimately means nothing with regard to how the function behaves.

Comment: Ok, fair enough, I was just interested since `std::copy` really looks like a typed version `std::memcpy`. But nothing is stopping me from looking at some implementations i guess.

Comment: The logic in this answer seems self-contradictory. If the problem is that `memcpy` doesn't know the destination and source types, and thus cannot be implemented safely, then... fair enough, I guess? But then you immediately contradict that by mentioning that compile-time pointers need to keep track of the true dynamic types of the objects they point to. Which means the compiler *knows* whether the arguments to `memcpy` are valid in a `constexpr` context or not, just as it does with `std::bit_cast`. At which point... why can't it allow the cases that should work, while disallowing the others?

Comment: @user541686: Because that would be really, really weird. Also, `memcpy` doesn't take pointers to objects; it takes pointers to memory (`void*`s). Which you can't generate at compile-time, because all of the operations that would convert a pointer to a `void*` are not constant expressions. And even if they were... why *not* create a function that explicitly exposes the interface you're using (copying object A as object B) rather than this ad-hoc nonsense (convert pointers to A and B to `void*`s, then do something)?

Comment: @NicolBolas: That's incorrect. Conversion to `void*` is just fine in `constexpr`. Conversion *from* `void*` is what doesn't work. And no, it isn't "really, really weird". If you feel it's weird for some calls to `memcpy` to succeed but others to fail - that's exactly what you said `std::bit_cast` already does, depending on whether pointers are present. This isn't any different. As for "why not create a function that explicitly copies A as B", well, `bit_cast` does that. But it doesn't work for smaller B.

Comment: Moreover, you want the code at runtime to look similar to the code doing the same thing at compile time. I'm not saying I'm in love with `memcpy`, but people are *supposed* to use `memcpy` to avoid violating strict aliasing, at least for cases where `std::bit_cast` isn't sufficient. So you might as well make it `constexpr` so they can do the same thing at compile time, instead of introducing a new function.

Comment: @user541686: "*that's exactly what you said std::bit_cast already does, depending on whether pointers are present*" But those are based on the *types* of the template provided. The signature of `memcpy` doesn't know what the types are, so it has no right to fail to compile. "*you want the code at runtime to look similar to the code doing the same thing at compile time.*" So switch your runtime code to `bit_cast`; it's not C++'s job to make bad, imprecise code work in compile-time code.

Comment: @user541686: "*at least for cases where std::bit_cast isn't sufficient*" And where exactly is that?

Comment: *"The signature of `memcpy` doesn't know what the types are, so it has no right to fail to compile."* Sure it does. `constexpr` contexts already perform dynamic checking in other cases -- try `struct S { unsigned int x; }; constexpr S s1 = {+1}, s2 = {-1};` and watch the *types* be woefully inadequate for predicting compilability. *"[...] And where exactly is that?"* I already mentioned it - one example of it is where the target type is smaller than the source, because `std::bit_cast` requires types of the exact same size, but that's not always what you want.

Comment: And in case an example with `void *` would hit closer to home, try this in GCC (Clang doesn't support the DR yet but [GCC supports it](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=111379)): `int main() { constexpr bool b = []() constexpr { int a[2] = {}, b[2] = {}; void *x = &a[0], *y = &a[1], *z = &b[0]; return x < y && y < z; }(); return b; }` Notice how [`x < y` is OK but `y < z` isn't](https://godbolt.org/z/KT5rnadEa), despite them all being the same `void *` type. Bottom line: dynamic checking is already all over the place in `constexpr` evaluation; they could do the same with `memcpy`.

Answer (score 2):

That's more a comment then an answer as I'm only citing what is written in [P0202R0: Add Constexpr Modifiers to Functions in  and  Headers](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0202r0.html#:%7E:text=std%3A%3Amemmove%20and%20std%3A%3Amemcpy%20accept%20void*%20and,const%5D.), but I write it here as is does not fit the comments:

> **B. `std::memmove` and `std::memcpy` must have constexpr additions**
> `std::memmove` and `std::memcpy` accept `void*` and `const void*` parameters. This makes them impossible to implement in pure C++ as `constexpr`, because constant expressions can not evaluate a conversion from type `cv void *` to a pointer-to-object type according to [expr.const].
> However those functions are not only popular, but also are widely used across Standard Library to gain better performance. Not making them constexpr will force standard Library developer to have compiler intrinsics for them anyway. This is a hard step that must be done.

The related section of `[expr.const]`:

> **8.6 Constant expressions [expr.const]**
> […]An expression `e` is a *core constant expression* unless the evaluation of `e`, following the rules of the abstract machine (6.8.1), would evaluate one of the following expressions:
> […]
> (2.13) — a conversion from type `cv void*` to a *pointer-to-object* type;