Does std::bit_cast incur an overhead?
I'm looking for legit use-cases of std::bit_cast in my code bases. Yet current cppreference documentation makes me wonder if it may induce an overhead by creating a (named) temporary object (thus not subject to mandatory copy/move elision).
Looking at the standard, It also says it returns a plain object that must be copied.
Is there really an overhead, what is the gain with respect to a mere std::memcpy to an existing object?
As an illustration, here is a contrived example where, ASFAIU, the std::bit_cast seems to imply much more assembly than the std::memcpy (not the best metric but I couldn't find an easiest way to illustrate my question):
//header.h
#ifndef HEADER
#define HEADER
#include <array>

class S {
   public:
    int val[1024] = {-1};
};

void SetBC(S& s,const std::array<char,sizeof(S)>& arr);
void SetMC(S& s,const std::array<char,sizeof(S)>& arr);

#endif

// main.cpp
#include "header.h"
#include <bit>
#include <cstring>

void SetBC(S& s,const std::array<char,sizeof(S)>& arr)
{
    s = std::bit_cast<S>(arr);
}
void SetMC(S& s,const std::array<char,sizeof(S)>& arr)
{
    std::memcpy(&s,arr.data(),sizeof(S));
}


instead of doing type some_obj; std::memcpy(&some_obj, &source, sizeof(source)); you can do auto some_obj = std::bit_cast<type>(source);.  They should have very similar performance.

@NathanOlivier, that's precisely the aim of my question. According to my test on CE, it's not implemented in the same way. (overwise the std::bit_cast clarify the intent)

You need to turn on optimizations.  They get almost the same assembly code when you do: https://godbolt.org/z/jaz8zMaP7

@Oersted it would help if you included a [mre] (with main, and with all the code arranged in one block so we can simply copy-paste it without separating to headers etc.).

Standard use of bit cast would be to manipulate individual bits within a pointer or maybe decode a floating point number using integer bit logic. Stuff like that, you can expect an optimizing compiler to understand without overhead. See for example here: https://godbolt.org/z/sh5Ev7raa

@NathanOliver oups I didn't see that I forgot optimization in my CE template. Updating the link (but implems seem to be still different)

@wohlstad I created different TU on purpose to avoid some compiler optimizations through "inlinin" (when using a single TU, the compiler sometime wipes out all the code and can guess directly the returned value)

@Oersted I see, fair enough.

One thing you get from bit_cast is that it checks for you at compile time if what you are doing is legal.  memcpy will just happily copy the bytes not caring if it invalidates anything.

@NathanOliver indeed but all these checks could be embedded around std::memcpy without changing the runtime implementation, the overhead (if any) would still be there. Don't you think so?

memcpy uses void*s so it can't check if the types of the objects provided are legal types for the function

The input and output of std::bit_cast must be trivial types. That means the ideal behavior must be at least as optimized as std::memcpy. If any platform behaves otherwise, you have a DR to file for a missed optimization.

@Red.Wave I would like to agree but it seems that no performance constraints have been given within the standard?

@Oersted not everything has to be explicitly demanded. std::bit_cast was finally standardized to address the type-punning issue in a portable and compile-time friendly(constexpr) solution. The implementation is platform specific, but std::memcpy has too many pitfalls and bit_cast is supposed to replace it.

If you are concerned about the performance I suggest creating a benchmark using quick-bench or something like it to see which one, if any, is faster than the other.  Without a real world test case and real world numbers we can only make educated guesses.  Personally I would use bit_cast as it better expresses intent than memcpy unless the numbers say its not worth it.

Interesting data point: if you change the compiler in your example to clang 19.1 (and remove -fanalyzer), it will optimize the code very similarly for both methods, with one key difference: your bitcast version will simply forward this to a call to memmove(), while your other version obviously calls memcpy(). It could be that bit_cast is always replaced by an inline version of memmove() by gcc, while memcpy() is replaced by an inline version of memcpy(). (I could not get gcc to drop the inlining for bitcast, even with -fno-inline.)

@Red.Wave you're rising an interesting point: the constexpre-ness of std::bit_cast (which is yet different from the question of the overhead). See https://stackoverflow.com/q/64041869/21691539. NB It may be worked-around by reinterpret_casting to arrays of char and using C++20 constexpr std::copy. I'd need to check if it would be UB.

@Oersted reinterpret_cast is not useable in a core constant expression.

Do you have the disassembly of the code?

In short, std::bit_cast must do the magic. If it doesn't, DR.

@NathanOliver damnit you're right!

the constexprness of bit_cast requires compiler support.  It is not something that can be done with standard C++.

@NathanOliver the implementation maybe an intrinsic or an extension to std C++(union, reinterpret_cast...). Either way is platform specific and unportable. So, the implementation on one specific platform can be UB in general sence(compiler can arbitrarily interpret UB). std just puts guarantees on the interface.


As an illustration, here is a contrived example where, ASFAIU, the std::bit_cast seems to imply much more assembly than the std::memcpy (not the best metric but I couldn't find an easiest way to illustrate my question):

The functions SetBC and SetMC can be compiled to identical assembly. If a compiler isn't doing that, it is a bug (in the sense of missed optimizations) in the compiler.

Looking at the standard, It also says it returns a plain object that must be copied.

Returning an object by value is a benefit over memcpy. It permits using the result to initialize a variable or returning it in a return statement, so that mandatory copy elision applies and it becomes unnecessary to first define and initialize a variable of the target type with some temporary state before storing the intended value in it.
Because you use an out-parameter in your example function, you lose that benefit again. If you attempt to rewrite the functions to return-by-value, you will see that the std::bit_cast version will be better.
Also, std::bit_cast is type-safe and can be used at compile-time. Both are further benefits over memcpy.
